# Agrupar Mensagens por data PHP, Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Campos principais `MYSQL`

`id, message, date`

Eu gostaria que fosse exibido desta forma no chat

```
26/02/2019
- message 1

27/02/2019
- message 2
- message 3
```

De certa forma eu consegui agrupar por data, abaixo está a forma que fiz.

Porém não consegui exibir no chat.

Até então, o que tenho, é isto em **PHP**

```
$messages = Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 2
            [message] => Mensagem 1
            [is_read] => 1
            [time] => 2019-02-26 10:32:55
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [from] => 2
            [to] => 1
            [message] => Mensagem 2
            [is_read] => 1
            [time] => 2019-02-27 08:33:40
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [from] => 1
            [to] => 2
            [message] => Mensagem 3
            [is_read] => 1
            [time] => 2019-02-27 08:38:20
        )

)

$sorted_date = [];
foreach ($messages as $message)
{
    $chat = [
        'msg'       => $message->id,
        'sender'    => $message->from, 
        'recipient' => $message->to,
        'avatar'    => 'no-image.jpg',
        'body'      => $message->message,
        'time'      => date("M j, Y, g:i a", strtotime($message->time)),
        'type'      => $message->from == $this->meu_id ? 'sender' : 'receiver',
        'name'      => $message->from == $this->meu_id ? 'You' : 0
    ];

    $timestamp = strtotime($message->time);
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
    if ( !isset($sorted_date[$date]) )
    {
        //$sorted_date[$date] = [$message];
        $sorted_date[$date] = [$chat];
        //array_push($sorted_date, $chat);
    }
    else
    {
        //$sorted_date[$date][] = $message;
        $sorted_date[$date][] = $chat;
    }
}

$response = [
    'success' => true,
    'thread'  => $sorted_date
];

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

**print_r ($sorted_date);**

```
Array
(
    [26-02-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [msg] => 1
                    [sender] => 1
                    [recipient] => 2
                    [avatar] => no-image.jpg
                    [body] => Mensagem 1
                    [time] => Feb 26, 2019, 10:32 am
                    [type] => sender
                    [name] => You
                )

        )

    [27-02-2019] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [msg] => 2
                    [sender] => 2
                    [recipient] => 1
                    [avatar] => no-image.jpg
                    [body] => Mensagem 2
                    [time] => Feb 27, 2019, 8:33 am
                    [type] => receiver
                    [name] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [msg] => 3
                    [sender] => 1
                    [recipient] => 2
                    [avatar] => no-image.jpg
                    [body] => Mensagem 3
                    [time] => Feb 27, 2019, 8:38 am
                    [type] => sender
                    [name] => You
                )

        )

)
```

**Isto é o que tenho no retorno do AJAX**

```js
success: (function (response) {
thread = response.thread;
$('.message-box').html('');
$.each(thread, function () {
        /* esta parte do código funciona, quando as mensagens não estão agrupadas */
 html = '<div class="message ' + this.type + '">' +
  '   <span>' + this.body + '</span>' +
  '       <span class="metadata">' +
  '       <span class="time">' + this.time + '</span>' +
  '   </span>' +
  '</div>';
 $('.message-box').append(html);
});
}),
```

Comment: Os valores principais retornam? Tipo, as datas retornam?

Comment: Sim, veja o print_r

Comment: Quis dizer no ajax. Desculpa

Comment: Veja o console https://i.imgur.com/P1u7mzt.png

Comment: Tenta assim: `$.each(thread, function(i, j){ console.log( j }) veja o que retorna

Comment: Aí me retorna isso: https://i.imgur.com/L7B33K8.png

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90323/discussion-between-adventistaam-and-wagner-filho).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que pirmeiro você deve agrupar o array dentro php

Minha sugestão é essa:

Dentro do seu loop, na função

```
 if ( !in_array_r( $date, $sorted_date  ))
    {
        $sorted_date[] = array( 
            'data' => $date,
            'message' => array( $chat )
        );
    }
    else
    {
        $key = array_seach_f($date, $sorted_date )  ;          
        $sorted_date[$key]['message'][] = $chat;
    }
```

E eu criei mais duas funções:

```
function in_array_r($item , $array) {
    return preg_match('/"'.preg_quote($item, '/').'"/i' , json_encode($array));
}
 function array_seach_f( $data, $array )
 {
     $index = -1;
     foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
         if( in_array( $data, $value ) ){
                $index = $key;
                break;
            } 
     }
     return $index;
 }
```

Daí você ppode tratar esse retorno no jquery

Comment: Para mim funcionou, obrigado..

Answer (score 0):

Minha sugestão é você usar as funções já nativas do PHP para isso, [aqui neste link da própria documentação do PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php) você encontrará vários exemplos de usar funções nativas do PHP tanto para strings, arrays, objetos e multi arrays e no final da pagina há vários exemplos adicionados pela própria comunidade.